# Django Binding POST request to class-based view

Tags: django, django-forms, django-class-based-views

I am trying to build a class based view to handle a review/update form. The form is built with the following code for the form:

```
    class ProcesoCandidato(forms.Form):
    ''''''
    hrfrmreclutado_nombres = forms.CharField()
    hrfrmreclutado_se_presento = forms.ChoiceField(
        choices=())
    hrfrmreclutado_cambio_de_cita = forms.DateField()
    hrfrmreclutado_entrevista = forms.ChoiceField()
    hrfrmreclutado_contratado = forms.ChoiceField()
    hrfrmreclutado_motivo_de_rechazo = forms.ChoiceField()
    hrfrmreclutado_notas = forms.CharField()

    def clean(self):
        ''''''
        cleaned_data = super(ProcesoCandidato, self).clean()
        clnfrmreclutado_nombres = \
        clnfrmreclutado_se_presento = \
            self.cleaned_data.get('hrfrmreclutado_se_presento', '')
        clnfrmreclutado_cambio_de_cita = \
            self.cleaned_data.get('hrfrmreclutado_cambio_de_cita', '')
        clnfrmreclutado_entrevista = \
            self.cleaned_data.get('hrfrmreclutado_entrevista', '')
        clnfrmreclutado_contratado = \
            self.cleaned_data.get('hrfrmreclutado_contratado', '')
        clnfrmreclutado_motivo_de_rechazo = \
            self.cleaned_data.get('hrfrmreclutado_motivo_de_rechazo', '')
        clnfrmreclutado_notas = \
            self.cleaned_data.get('hrfrmreclutado_notas', '')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ''''''
        super(ProcesoCandidato, self).__init__()

        self.fields['hrfrmreclutado_se_presento'].choices = [
            ('', '------'),
            ('Si', 'Si'),
            ('No', 'No'),
            ]
        self.fields['hrfrmreclutado_entrevista'].choices = [
            ('', '------'),
            ('Si', 'Si'),
            ('No', 'No'),
            ]
        self.fields['hrfrmreclutado_contratado'].choices = [
            ('', '------'),
            ('Si', 'Si'),
            ('No', 'No'),
            ]
        self.fields['hrfrmreclutado_motivo_de_rechazo'].choices = \
            [('', '------')] + [(c.pk, c.razonrechazo)
                for c in models.RazonRechazo.objects.all()]
```

The views file contains a class based view to handle the GET and POST methods:

```
class ProcesoRH(View):
''''''
form_class = ProcesoCandidato
initial = {
    'procesorh_llego': 'No',
    'procesorh_entrevista': 'No',
    'procesorh_contratado': 'No',
    'procesorh_rechazo': '',
    'procesorh_notas': ''}
template_name = 'sitio_rh/rhprocess.html'

def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    reclutadoid = request.GET['candidato']
    procesodata = models.ProcesoRH.objects.filter(
        procesorh_reclutado_id=reclutadoid)

    if procesodata.exists() is False:
        objproceso = models.ProcesoRH()
        objproceso.procesorh_reclutado_id = reclutadoid
        objproceso.save()
    else:
        pass

    reclutadodata = models.Reclutado.objects.get(pk=reclutadoid)
    form = self.form_class(initial=self.initial)
    edad = self.cualedad(request, reclutadoid)

    return render(request, self.template_name, {
    'form': form,
    'username': self.request.user,
    'titulo': 'Proceso de Entrevista - RH',
    'marca': 'Plataforma electronica de Reclutamiento',
    'section': 'Proceso RH',
    'candidatoinfo': reclutadodata,
    'rhdata': procesodata,
    'reclutadoedad': edad
    })

def post(self, request, *args, **krargs):
    form = self.form_class(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        sucess = form.is_valid()
        return HttpResponse(sucess)
    else:
       error = ('Bound: %s Valid: %s') % (form.is_bound, form.is_valid())
       return HttpResponse(error)

def cualedad(self, request, reclutadoid):
    '''Calcular la edad a partir de la fecha de nacimiento'''
    reclutadodata = models.Reclutado.objects.get(pk=reclutadoid)
    reclutadonacimiento = reclutadodata.rec_fecha_nacimiento
    fechaactual = datetime.date.today()
    deltaedad = (fechaactual - reclutadonacimiento)
    edad = int(deltaedad.days) / 365
    return edad.__int__()

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    ''' Instanciamiento, obtenemos los valores iniciales.'''
    super(ProcesoRH, self).__init__()
```

The view works fine for the GET method, which identifies a record, retrieves the data that already exists, and places it as the initial data for the form.
The form itself, once rendered has an "update" button, that triggers the POST action. When I get to the POST method, I can retrieve that the form is unbound and invalid. I understand that I need to bound the form to the data updated/added before trying the is_valid method, but I have been unable to do so. Any guidance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why are you doing this? There are already class-based views for processing forms, you should use one of those rather than the base View. You should almost never need to define `get` (or `post`).

Comment: But that said, binding a form to the POST data is not any different in class-based views than it is in function-based views, and you've done it correctly, so it's not clear what your question is.

Comment: Finally, note that your form `clean` method does nothing useful, and you never do anything at all (either in the form or the view) with the results of the form data.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have other function based form processing that work fine, So I am attempting to do a class based view because of the added flexibility. The issue is that while I am trying to do the binding I still cannot create an instance that will allow the form to be validated.

Comment: Also, the reason I am using a generic view class is that the data collected by the form goes to different models, I have not figured out how to make a form for a model with foreign key relation ships (greenhorn Django user here)

Comment: I am going back to basics and try to rewrite this as a function

Comment: Found the problem. The problem was in the class definition and how arguments where being passed to the method POST.